# Wait for next user task in camunda by REST

Tags: rest, bpmn, camunda

We have a mobile application which will call by REST an user task to input some data and complete it. Then the process will go through some other service tasks which will validate this input. Then the process may stop at "Wait for user data" user task again (recursive flow), coz it need more data, or it can go to another user task such as "Accept terms of service".

What's the recommended way to make my mobile application input those data variables, complete the "wait for user data" and then get the new task? how to wait until the process stop in the next user task, and know if it is "wait for user data" or "accept terms of service"?

Answer (score 0):

If the follow up service task is only validating inputs, the by far easiest solution is to move the validation to the complete operation of your userTask.
So you can only leave the task when it is fulfilled.

If you really need to leave the task and then check if it is needed again, you can use the Ui Mediator Pattern as described in [this blog](http://www.bpm-guide.de/2012/04/04/pageflow-vs-process-flow-and-ui-mediator-pattern/).